# QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName error

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Probably the solutions is trivial, but after deleting a ButtonBox from a dialog, I get the following error:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_buttonBox_accepted()
```

There is a slot with that name in the dialog class, and I use it.
I have no idea why the Qt thinks, that there should be an other signal, connected to that slot. (I checked the c++ and the .ui xml files)

Comment: clean your project, and rebuild. still the same error ?

Comment: [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) is expecting an object named `buttonBox` with an `accepted` signal, but as you said you deleted such object.

Comment: @thuga it is possible that a generated header file has not been updated.

Comment: @UmNyobe He said he is still using that slot. *There is a slot with that name in the dialog class, and I use it.*

Comment: I deleted the build folder, and the error remains. @thuga: Do you mean, that based on the slot name, the Qt meta compiler tries to connect it to the corresponding signal?

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yes. When you use the `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);` syntax to name your slots, it will try to do that. `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` is called somewhere in your `ui_classname.h` file. Rename your slot to something else, for example remove the `on_` part.

Comment: Post the code, how you made the connection

Comment: @thuga gotcha. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) is expecting an object named `buttonBox` with an `accepted` signal, but as you said you deleted such object.

When you use the `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);` syntax to name your slots, `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` will try connect that slot to a signal by name. `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` is called somewhere in your `ui_classname.h` file.

To solve this, rename your slot to something else, for example remove the `on_` part.